# Webpack Bundle Analyzer gives error EACCES

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I just found out about webpack bundle analyzer through [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-did-angular-cli-budgets-save-my-day-and-how-they-can-save-yours-300d534aae7a) link and went to try it out.  I was able to run the build and get a stats.json file, however when I run:

```
webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/RDPortal/stats.json
```

I get this error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8888
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1517:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I tried googling the error and webpack bundle analyzer, etc. but couldn't find anything significant that helped.  I'm building from the WebStorm IDE in an Angular project and as mentioned the stats.json generates fine (32mb, holy cow).

I did also run the install as `npm i webpack-bundle-analyzer` in case that matters...

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: This usually means port is already in use.. You need to kill the program using the above mentioned port

Comment: Hmm, I'm not aware of anything that would have been using that port at the time.  How would I find out what was using it?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 x64...

Comment: In command prompt type following....
1. netstat -aon | findstr 8888 <-- to find pid of application running on '8888'.... 
2. taskkill /F /PID pid_number <--- to kill application

Comment: Cool thank you!  Ended up being a Seagate monitor application that was using that port.  Unfortunately the command prompt failed to kill it with access denied, but I was able to find it in task manager and kill it and then all worked as expected.  Make it an answer and I will accept...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually means port is already in use.. You need to kill the program using the above mentioned port.

As you are using Windows 10 x64, perform the following activities

In command prompt type following

1. netstat -aon | findstr 8888 <-- to find pid of application running on '8888'
2. taskkill /F /PID pid_number <--- to kill application

Comment: On my computer I need `taskkill //F //PID pid_number` (double splash instead)